# Using serverless-mocha-plugin to test dynamic endpoint

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, serverless, aws-serverless

I am creating an API application in NodeJS using the Serverless framework. I have installed the `serverless-mocha-plugin` and am trying to create some unit tests for my functions.

In my `serverless.yml` file, I have the following endpoints:

```
...
equipmentGetAll:
  handler: ./api/equipment/equipment.getAll
  events:
   - http:
     path: equipment
     method: get
     cors: true
equipmentGetOne:
  handler: ./api/equipment/equipment.getOne
  events:
    - http:
      path: equipment/{po_number}
      method: get
      cors: true
...
```

When testing the `getAll` endpoint, I use the following test which passes successfully. I have verified it works by logging the response to the console.

```
'use strict';

// tests for equipmentGetAll
// Generated by serverless-mocha-plugin

const mochaPlugin = require('serverless-mocha-plugin');
const expect = mochaPlugin.chai.expect;
let wrapped = mochaPlugin.getWrapper('equipmentGetAll', '/api/equipment/equipment.js', 'getAll');

describe('equipmentGetAll', () => {
  before((done) => {
    done();
  });

  it('should get all Equipment', () => {
    return wrapped.run({po_number:117}).then((response) => {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
      expect(response.body.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Similarly, for the `getOne`endpoint, I am (for now) doing a very similar test:

```
'use strict';

// tests for equipmentGetOne
// Generated by serverless-mocha-plugin

const mochaPlugin = require('serverless-mocha-plugin');
const expect = mochaPlugin.chai.expect;
let wrapped = mochaPlugin.getWrapper('equipmentGetOne', '/api/equipment/equipment.js', 'getOne');

describe('equipmentGetOne', () => {
  before((done) => {
    done();
  });

  it('should get one single Equipment', () => {
    return wrapped.run({}).then((response) => {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
      expect(response.body.length).to.be.equal(1);
    });
  });
});
```

**The Problem**

The current response I'm receiving for `getOne` is:

```
{ 
  statusCode: 500,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
  body: 'Cannot read property \'po_number\' of undefined' 
}
```

Due to the fact that the **path** for `getOne` from `serverless.yml` is `equipment/{po_number}` rather than just `equipment/`.

What is the proper way to pass the path value for the test?

A sample call would hit endpoint `my-api-endpoint.com/equipment/117` and return the Equipment with `po_number` `117`. This works properly when testing with POSTMan, but how can I make it work with `mocha-serverless-plugin`?

Comment: Any updates? Got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to lambda you should use
 `wrappedLambda.run({body: "String, not Object"})`

To pass queryStringParametr to lambda you should use  `wrappedLambda.run({queryStringParameters: {a: "first",b:"second"}})`

To pass pathParameters to lambda you should use       
 `wrappedLambda.run({pathParameters: {a: "first", b:"second"})`

Simple example for testing post method

```
 context('save flashcard', () => {
        before((done) => {
            done();
        });
        it('save flashcard successfully', () => {
            return saveFlashcard.run({body: correctInput})
                .then((response) => {
                    const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    expect(body).to.have.property('_id')
                })
        });
});
```

this body will be located inside event object.

Answer (score 0):

To pass body you need to do something like this

```
{
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    releaseDate: 2231213213,
    title: 'sfsdf',
    authorName: 'L'
  })
}
```